# what is the wrong with this example in the c++ book of Bjarne Stroustrup

Tags: c++, c++11

I tried the example in bjarne stroustrup's c++ programming language 4th edition:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
using Iterator<T> = typename T::iterator;

template<typename C, typename V>
vector<Iterator<C>> find_all(C& c, V v)
{
    vector<Iterator<C>> res;
    for (auto p = c.begin(); p!=c.end(); ++p)
        if (*p==v)
            res.push_back(p);
    return res;
}

void test()
{
    string m {"Mary had a little lamb"};
    for (auto p : find_all(m,'a'))
        if (*p!='a')
            cerr << "string bug!\n";
    // p is a str ing::iterator
    list<double> ld {1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 1.1};
    for (auto p : find_all(ld,1.1))
        if (*p!=1.1)
            cerr << "list bug!\n";
    vector<string> vs { "red", "blue", "green", "green", "orange", "green" };
    for (auto p : find_all(vs,"green"))
        if (*p!="green")
            cerr << "vector bug!\n";
    for (auto p : find_all(vs,"green"))
        *p = "ver t";
}

int main()
{
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

§4.5.1

I compile the code with:
g++ test.cpp -o test -g -std=c++11 on ubuntu, but I got the errors below:

```
iterator_of_iterator_version_2.cpp:9:15: error: expected ‘=’ before ‘<’ token
 using Iterator<T> = typename T::iterator;
               ^
iterator_of_iterator_version_2.cpp:9:15: error: expected type-specifier before ‘<’ token
iterator_of_iterator_version_2.cpp:12:8: error: ‘Iterator’ was not declared in this scope
 vector<Iterator<C>> find_all(C& c, V v)
        ^
iterator_of_iterator_version_2.cpp:12:17: error: template argument 1 is invalid
 vector<Iterator<C>> find_all(C& c, V v)
                 ^
iterator_of_iterator_version_2.cpp:12:17: error: template argument 2 is invalid
iterator_of_iterator_version_2.cpp:12:18: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘>’ token
 vector<Iterator<C>> find_all(C& c, V v)
                  ^
iterator_of_iterator_version_2.cpp: In function ‘void test()’:
iterator_of_iterator_version_2.cpp:24:30: error: ‘find_all’ was not declared in this scope
  for (auto p : find_all(m,'a'))
                              ^
iterator_of_iterator_version_2.cpp:29:31: error: ‘find_all’ was not declared in this scope
  for (auto p : find_all(ld,1.1))
                               ^
iterator_of_iterator_version_2.cpp:33:35: error: ‘find_all’ was not declared in this scope
  for (auto p : find_all(vs,"green"))
                                   ^
iterator_of_iterator_version_2.cpp:36:35: error: ‘find_all’ was not declared in this scope
  for (auto p : find_all(vs,"green"))
                                   ^
```

So what is the problem?

It seems that no syntax error can be found in this code because I just did a copy-paste of the example of the book.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I did that, same errors

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4)

Comment: shouldnt it be 'template<class T> using Iterator = typename T::iterator'

Comment: Have you copied the code from the book correctly? Because like @jonas_toth says you should not have the template argument for the type-alias.

Comment: i quicktested it, compiles with same compiler. that <T> was too much

Comment: @jonas_toth exactly! I don't know why but this works.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude what i did is ctrl-c & ctrl-v, I am sure that it is the copy of the example in the book.

Comment: Stroustrup has written several books about C++, but you don't say which one. You can find the errata sheets for yours using the search engine of your choice. If this one isn't there, here's what Stroustrup says: "The reader is supposed to be sufficiently experimeenced not to get confused by simple typos." (No, the code as printed is usually never tested. That costs money.)

Comment: @molbdnilo My bad, I should have done that, now I did it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the beginning from

```
template<typename T>
using Iterator<T> = typename T::iterator;
```

to

```
template<typename T>
using Iterator = typename T::iterator;
```

Works on my ubuntu 16.04 with probably same compiler setup

Why is it that way? I am not 100percent confident about that, someone else might verify it please.

Writing

```
using Iterator<T>
```

is invalid, because it doesnt make sense here. We want Iterator to be a templated typedef that will ask its parameter-type for its generic iterator type. 
`Iterator<T>` would specialize the template.
E.g. we know it better for a specific type:

```
template<>
using Iterator<MyClass> = MyClassIterator;
```

At least that works with normal template classes, i think its the same with using as well.

Comment: But could you explain that? Why is it behaving like this?

Comment: this is rather syntactic. using Iterator<T> would be a template specialization (i guess), but that is now wanted. What is wanted is a template Iterator. but iam not confident with the c++ language requirements behind it. i will update it in the answer with my naive understanding

Comment: It was a typo in the example code.  It happens.  Possibly the example was written when `using` template alias syntax was different, or didn't exist!

Comment: updated the post, maybe its a little be clearer now why it is problematic (and has a bad error message :D)

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
 template<typename T>
 using Iterator<T> = typename T::iterator;
```

to this

```
template<typename T>
using Iterator = typename T::iterator;
```